# How to decode a json string with gson in java?

Tags: java, json, social-networking

I have a json string (the stream of social network Qaiku). How can I decode it in Java? 
I've searched but any results work for me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an example using Gson, you could do the following

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(value, type);
```

where value is your encoded value.  The trick comes with the second parameter - the type.  You need to know what your decoding and what Java type that JSON will end in.

The following example shows decoding a JSON string into a list of domain objects called Table:

http://javastorage.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/how-to-decode-json-with-google-gson-library/

In order to do that the type needs to be specified as:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Table>>(){}.getType();
```

Gson is available here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 9):

Standard way of object de-serialization is the following:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyType obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyType.class);
```

For primitives corresponding class should be used instead of MyType.

You can find more details in [Gson user's guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). If this way does not work for you - probably there's some error in JSON input.